# Has anyone integrated ROS with Unity 3d?

Tags: ros, integration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You know: [www.unity3d.com](http://www.unity3d.com), runs Mono. Prefer Windows, but understand that Mac might be closer to supportable.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/123641/has-anyone-integrated-ros-with-unity-3d?/) by [daveayyyy](https://answers.ros.org/users/11371/daveayyyy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-01-28

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) on 2014-01-28**:
What kind of integration are you talking about?

**Comment by [daveayyyy](https://answers.ros.org/users/11371/daveayyyy/) on 2014-01-28**:
Using C# to talk to native, DLL, or websocket, for example. Want to be able to interact with the 3D model of my building to tell robot where to go, have robot tell me where it is and reflect that in the model.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-01-28**:
I integrated untiy via DLL + socket conection to player/stage 3 years ago . Was quite a bit of work. Haven't heard any thing about ROS+Unity, would be awesome, though.

**Comment by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) on 2015-04-06**:
Is there anyone who has got his/her hands dirty on that (viz. ROS+Unity3D) ?

**Comment by [pavan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25676/pavan/) on 2016-06-17**:
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=7392488

These guys have done quite a bit in making unity and ROS speak. But sadly, they say nothing about their code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosbridge` is a great way to make a websocket which can stream data via restful api. You can use `rosbridge` to get topics from ROS to unity. I've done this myself but one caveat is that PointCloud2 topics are bugged in indigo to the point that the streaming doesn't work for those types.

Here's a great example to get you started with streaming topics form a kinect: http://wiki.ros.org/ros3djs/Tutorials/Point%20Cloud%20Streaming%20from%20a%20Kinect

Also, do ingest the data via Unity3d you merely point it at the web service.

---

Originally posted by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) with karma: 396 on 2016-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have recently published our ROS-Unity3D Toolbox ROS#  on GitHub: https://github.com/siemens/ros-sharp

We use rosbridge_suite on the ROS side and implemented RosBridgeClient in C# (using websocket-sharp and newtonsoft json.net).

Our toolbox also has a URDF importer for Unity3d which downloads URDF, meshes and textures from ROS and models the robot with all its kinematics in Unity3D.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Bischoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/29109/martin-bischoff/) with karma: 71 on 2017-10-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Demian23](https://answers.ros.org/users/24665/demian23/) on 2017-11-23**:
Not sure if I can ask you elsewhere, so I ask here: I implemented the ros-sharp toolkit in an existing unity project and even set up a new one but got a error compiling the projects. Something with the newsonsoft.json has problems. It could be because we use the hololens toolkit too. Any suggestions

**Comment by [Martin Bischoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/29109/martin-bischoff/) on 2017-11-23**:
@Demian23 please provide a clear error description so that we can help you.

Problems with ROS#: Please write detailed issues here: https://github.com/siemens/ros-sharp/issues

Unity3D, Hololens, Json.NET Problems: https://answers.unity.com/questions/ask.html